# From given integer value, how to print first two digit and then last two digit values in java

Tags: java

```
int a=1256;
int b=34;
```

Now i want to print as below.

```
System.out.println(**First two digit from (a)** +b+ **and last two digit from (a)**);
```

help me out of this!

Comment: What is your try to solve this problem.

Comment: First think about this, without thinking about how to code it in Java: how would you calculate the first and last two digits of a number?

Comment: Be sure first that always (user inputs) you can get first two and last ...

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `Integer.toString(value)` and than print the substring.
Something like that:

```
Integer a = new Integer(1256);
String aStr = a.toString();
System.out.println(aStr.substring(0,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first digit of an `int` can be given with a while loop : divide by 10 until you're under 10, or use the `String` version which is easier to use

- 1st digit : `String.valueOf(number).charAt(0)`
- last digit : `number%10`

Then concatenate them all, the `""+` is to avoid mathematic sum between them

```
System.out.println("" + String.valueOf(a).charAt(0) + b + (a%10)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we need first 2 digits we should divide it by 100.
For the last 2 digits, apply mod 100 on the given number to get remainder which is the last 2 digits.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=1256;
    int b=34;
    System.out.println(a/100+"" +b+ ""+a%100); // Output: 123456
    System.out.println(a/100+" " +b+ " "+a%100); // Output: 12 34 56
    }
}
```

The first `System.out.println` is without spaces and the second `System.out.println` is with spaces.

Comment: Hii Ankit, If I get values from user by randomly, I want to print it as in the sequence

Comment: Eg:- user enter 4896 and second time they entered 89

Comment: Now i want print 488996